# How to receive notifications when a key is pressed in any child view of a containing view

Tags: android

I am writing an app that computes a "net income" number based on "additions to income" and "deductions from income." I have two different layouts--one for tablets and one for phones. The tablet version shows a much more detailed questionnaire and the phone version shows a shorter form.

Here's the XML for the "long form." I took out a bunch of TableRows for this posting because I didn't want to just have the XML blather on and on. Other than that, this is exactly what I'm using. (There are two tables, side by side).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/input_layout"
    >
    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout0" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
      <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content">

          <!-- Table appearing on left side prompting for additions to income -->
        <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow0" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="@string/income"></TextView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView style="@style/leftIndentText" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:text="@string/gross_income"></TextView>
                <EditText style="@style/NumericInput" android:id="@+id/textGrossIncome">
                    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
                </EditText>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView style="@style/leftIndentText" android:text="@string/pay_frequency"/>
                <Spinner style="@style/Spinner" 
                    android:id="@+id/PayFrequency" 
                    android:entries="@array/pay_frequency_choices"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView style="@style/leftIndentText" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:text="@string/investment_income"></TextView>
                <EditText style="@style/NumericInput"  android:id="@+id/textInvestmentIncome"></EditText>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

          <!-- Table appearing on rightside prompting for deductions from income -->
          <TableLayout>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="@string/deductions"></TextView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView style="@style/leftIndentText" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:text="@string/unreimb_bus_exp"></TextView>
                <EditText style="@style/NumericInput" android:id="@+id/textUnreimbBusExp"></EditText>
            </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The calculations are done in a separate class that just addes up all the additions to income, subtracts the deductions from income, and provides a net number. I want the class that computes the answer to be updated each time the user leaves an input field. So my great vision was to have an onFocusChangeListener attached to each input field.

Here's the problem I'm facing. What I was hoping to do was figure out a way to get notified when any EditText view lost focus WITHOUT having to explicitly set an onFocusChangeListener on each EditText view. My reasoning is that this app deals with the laws in individual states and there are different inputs for each state. They all boil down to additions to and deductions from income.

I've been all over the Android developer forums and this site, and I just can't figure out how to do it. The path I went down, which hasn't worked, is to set an onFocusChangeListener on the TableView that contains the EditText views, but I haven't been able to get that to work.

The way I tried to do that is when the Fragment gets created and it's View is inflated, I added a callback at that point, i.e.

```
public class InputFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflator, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.input_fragment_layout, container, false);
        View table = view.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout0);

        try
        {
            table.setFocusable(true);
            table.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
                {
                    Log.e("TJD1", "Focus change event");
                }

            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("TJD1", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

I also considered trying to iterate over each of the EditText views when the Fragment is created, but I can't figure out how to do that either.

Any pointers in the right direction would be so very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @CommonsWare, I came up with the following solution to my post and wanted to share it in case anyone else faces a similar problem and can't come up with a better solution than this:

First, in my layout XML, I changed the ID strings for each input field. For example, I was using something like this:

```
<EditText style="@style/NumericInput" android:id="@+id/textSSI"></EditText>
```

Instead, now I'm using this:

```
<EditText style="@style/NumericInput" android:id="@+redinc/textSSI"></EditText>
```

The difference being that instead of using "id", I'm using "redinc" (for reductions to income) or "addinc" for additions to income.

Then in my Fragment, I'm able to use Java's Reflection API to discover the members of the R.redinc and R.addinc static classes. That enables me to loop through all the controls without my code having to know in advance the ids of all the particular controls, which will help me implement different versions of this app for different states and different device formats. My new Fragment looks like this. (BTW: Focus may not be the right event to hook into, but I stuck with it for this example).

```
public class InputFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflator, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.e("TJD1", "InputFragment View Created");
        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.input_fragment_layout, container, false);

        Field[] fields = R.addinc.class.getDeclaredFields();
        addHandlers(fields, view);

        fields = R.redinc.class.getDeclaredFields();
        addHandlers(fields, view);

        return view;
    }

    private void addHandlers(Field[] fields, View view)
    {
        for (Field field : fields)
        {
            Log.e("TJD1", "Adding focus handler for " + field.getName());
            try
            {
                View input = view.findViewById(field.getInt(null));
                input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
                    {
                        String comment = hasFocus ? " gained focus" : " lost focus";
                        Log.e("TJD1", v.toString() + comment);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                Log.e("TJD1", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                Log.e("TJD1", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So my great vision was to have an onFocusChangeListener attached to each input field.

That might make sense on a desktop or notebook. On a touchscreen-dominated device, users aren't going to "tab" to another field very often. Since they're going to have to tap something to recalculate anyway (focus won't be changing otherwise), you may as well simply have them tap something to recalculate. Put the recalculate button and output fields outside of the `ScrollView`, and the button and results will be just one tap away.

> What I was hoping to do was figure out a way to get notified when any EditText view lost focus WITHOUT having to explicitly set an onFocusChangeListener on each EditText view.

If you are going to create a mile-long form, you need to do the programming for the mile-long form.

> The path I went down, which hasn't worked, is to set an onFocusChangeListener on the TableView that contains the EditText views, but I haven't been able to get that to work.

There is no `TableView`; I assume you mean either `TableLayout` or `TableRow`. In neither case do those widgets get the focus, because they are not focusable.

> I also considered trying to iterate over each of the EditText views when the Fragment is created, but I can't figure out how to do that either.

Create an array with the widget IDs. Iterate over the array. Inside the loop, call `findViewById()` to get the widget.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. For my particular user audience, having them take any extra step is a barrier--they tend to be attorneys in the midst of a trial. Creating an array of ids where that array is hardcoded into the application is a nonstarter for the reasons I articulated in my question. However, your suggestion of using an array of IDs helped me think of the solution that I posted. Thanks again for your prompt response and for providing the inspiration for a solution!

Comment: OK. **Will** post. As a new user I can't "self answer" for another 5 hours. But the solution involved renaming the ids of the input fields so that in the R class, there is a new static class containing just the input fields as memebers. Having done that, I used Java's reflection API to get a list of views which I can iterate through and for which I can then register event handlers. By using this approach, any changes to the layout XML will automatically feed through the rest of the application. Thanks again @CommonsWare for providing the inspiration for a flexible solution.

Comment: "For my particular user audience, having them take any extra step is a barrier--they tend to be attorneys in the midst of a trial." -- there is no extra step. Either they tap on a `Button` or they tap on a totally pointless other `EditText` to force a focus change. A tap is a tap is a tap.